# Highscores activity

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I'm pretty new to android-programming. 
Can you help me, what i need to show local highscores table in this activity? 
Am I need to create some TextViews in it and in xml?
Where I can found some examples to see how it works?

Highscore activity

```
import game.main.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Highscores extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.highscores);      


    }
}
```

HighscoreList class

```
package game.objectsmain;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public class HighScoresList { 
private SharedPreferences preferences; 
private String names[]; 
private long score[]; 

    public HighScoresList(Context context) 
    { 
        preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("Highscore", 0); 
        names = new String[5]; 
        score = new long[5]; 

        for (int x=0; x<5; x++) 
        { 
            names[x] = preferences.getString("name"+x, "-"); 
            score[x] = preferences.getLong("score"+x, 0); 
        } 

    } 

    public String getName(int x) 
    { 
        //get the name of the x-th position in the Highscore-List 
        return names[x]; 
    } 

    public long getScore(int x) 
    { 
        //get the score of the x-th position in the Highscore-List 
        return score[x]; 
    } 

    public boolean inHighscore(long score) 
    { 
    //test, if the score is in the Highscore-List 
        int position; 
        for (position=0; position<10 && this.score[position] > score; position++); 

        if (position==5) return false; 
        return true; 
    } 

    public boolean addScore(String name, long score) 
    { 
    //add the score with the name to the Highscore-List 
        int position; 
        for (position=0; position<10 && this.score[position] > score; position++); 

        if (position==5) return false; 

        for (int x=4; x > position; x--) 
        { 
            names[x]=names[x-1]; 
            this.score[x]=this.score[x-1]; 
        } 

        this.names[position] = new String(name); 
        this.score[position] = score; 

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit(); 
        for (int x=0; x<5; x++) 
        { 
            editor.putString("name"+x, this.names[x]); 
            editor.putLong("score"+x, this.score[x]); 
        } 
        editor.commit(); 
        return true; 

    } 

}
```

P.S.
btw is it ok to use shared preferences or use sqlite database is much better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your highscores to be available on the internet, take a look at [OpenFeint](http://openfeint.com).

Now, if its just a local table,

There's nothing wrong with using eithor `SharedPreferences` or SQLite Database.

I can tell you, using a SQLite Database will be much easier than SharedPreferences.
(Why? Because you wont have to manually sort, validate, check for duplicates in the case of Databases...A Simple Query/Statement can list the top 10, truncate old scores, etc instantly.

To Display your High Score Table, Use a `ListActivity` and  Custom List Adapter to display each Entry. [Here](http://jnastase.alner.net/archive/2010/12/19/custom-android-listadapter.aspx)'s a nice relevant tutorial for the same.

Comment: thank you. but i don't understood clearly how to transfer scores which i get into highscores menu. i mean for my realization.

Comment: @user1107378, Google for Custom Cursor Adapter. (assuming you are using database)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need TextViews. You can add them in your R.layout.highscores XML or you can add them programmatically. There are hundreds of examples, just Google on "Android TextView example".

Also, it is ok to use shared preferences but sqlite db is much faster.

Comment: Lars Vogel has nice tutorials: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: No, not how to use SQLite or SharedPrefs. I know how to do that. I mean do you have any sources which attest that SQLite is "much faster" than the shared prefs. I don't see that, but I have no time for a sample project at the moment.

Comment: Well, the shared prefs are stored in an xml file. The SharedPreferences class is just an xml data parser/writer.